# Uncaught reference error - the functionName is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="e">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Practice Java Script </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssjs/csspracticejs.css">
<script scr="javajs/java.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Changing the Style</h1>
<p>JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="openMe()">Open!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="closeMe()">Close!</button>
<p id="demo">Extra details...You can open and close this paragraph using the 
buttons above.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my javascript

```
    function closeMe(){
    x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.display="none";
}

    function openMe(){
    x=document.getElementById("demo");
     x.style.display="block";}
```

But when I try to run it, it appears as Uncaught ReferenceError: closeMe is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (HTML.html:13). Could you please help to see where i did wrong ?

Comment: The code you provided seems to be working...

Comment: Does the other function (`openMe()`) work?

Comment: Is that your entire JS code? Or are the functions defined only in a local scope?

Comment: <script **scr** >  ← should be src

Comment: No, function openMe() also does not work. It has the same problem

Comment: Yes, its the entire code, I just want to check why the script does not work, I think I will check the source again

Comment: Please read JJJ's comment !!!! It has been upvoted three times for a reason.

Comment: It works!! Thanks JJJ!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo error during importing script.

It should be `<script src>` not `<script scr>`.